# Select first row where value of another column is true

Tags: sql, presto

Here is my base table. I'm trying to add a column where I would see the approved date.

| date | customer_id | approved |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/23 | a | false |
| 01/01/23 | b | false |
| 02/01/23 | a | true |
| 02/01/23 | b | false |
| 03/01/23 | a | true |
| 03/01/23 | b | true |

Here is what I want to get where I can see the approved date for each customer_id. In this example a would have an approved date of 02/01/23 and b would have an approved date of 03/01/23.

| date | customer_id | approved | approved_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/23 | a | false | 02/01/23 |
| 01/01/23 | b | false | 03/01/23 |
| 02/01/23 | a | true | 02/01/23 |
| 02/01/23 | b | false | 03/01/23 |
| 03/01/23 | a | true | 02/01/23 |
| 03/01/23 | b | true | 03/01/23 |

I am using SQL presto if that helps.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the `MIN` window function, which attempts to select only dates where approved = true (per conditional aggregation), then retrieve the minimum date.

```
SELECT date_, 
       customer_id, 
       approved, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN approved = true THEN date_ END) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id) 
FROM tab
ORDER BY date_
```

Output:

| date_ | customer_id | approved | min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | a | false | 2023-02-01 |
| 2023-01-01 | b | false | 2023-03-01 |
| 2023-02-01 | a | true | 2023-02-01 |
| 2023-02-01 | b | false | 2023-03-01 |
| 2023-03-01 | a | true | 2023-02-01 |
| 2023-03-01 | b | true | 2023-03-01 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6G6fUab6QrF3Jo9GRD3NRm/0).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Window function for `MIN()` aggregation along with a conditional such as

```
SELECT t.*,
       MIN(CASE WHEN approved = 'true' THEN date END) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) AS approved_date
  FROM t
```